# Suggestion to Reduce Number of code lines - Unix

Tags: linux, if-statement, sed, while-loop

I am trying to update the file permission of`test_1.txt` available as content inside the main file `test.txt` based on the value available in the variable `IN`. Below script will help to modify the content as per my requirement. But I need to reduce the number of lines of code. so could you suggest any way to reduce the number of lines and achieve the same output.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
IN=750
Input=test.txt
Char_one=$(echo $IN | cut -c 1)
Char_two=$(echo $IN | cut -c 2)
Char_three=$(echo $IN | cut -c 3)

if [[ "$Char_one" == "7" ]]; then 
 Char_one="rwx"
elif [[ "$Char_one" == "6" ]]; then 
 Char_one="rw-"
elif [[ "$Char_one" == "5" ]]; then 
 Char_one="r-x"
elif [[ "$Char_one" == "4" ]]; then 
 Char_one="r--"
elif [[ "$Char_one" == "3" ]]; then 
 Char_one="-wx"
elif [[ "$Char_one" == "2" ]]; then     
 Char_one="rwx"
elif [[ "$Char_one" == "1" ]]; then     
 Char_one="-w-"
elif [[ "$Char_one" == "0" ]]; then     
 Char_one="---"
fi

if [[ "$Char_two" == "7" ]]; then 
 Char_two="rwx"
elif [[ "$Char_two" == "6" ]]; then 
 Char_two="rw-"
elif [[ "$Char_two" == "5" ]]; then 
 Char_two="r-x"
elif [[ "$Char_two" == "4" ]]; then 
 Char_two="r--"
elif [[ "$Char_two" == "3" ]]; then 
 Char_two="-wx"
elif [[ "$Char_two" == "2" ]]; then     
 Char_two="rwx"
elif [[ "$Char_two" == "1" ]]; then     
 Char_two="-w-"
elif [[ "$Char_two" == "0" ]]; then     
 Char_two="---"
fi

if [[ "$Char_three" == "7" ]]; then 
 Char_three="rwx"
elif [[ "$Char_three" == "6" ]]; then 
 Char_three="rw-"
elif [[ "$Char_three" == "5" ]]; then 
 Char_three="r-x"
elif [[ "$Char_three" == "4" ]]; then 
 Char_three="r--"
elif [[ "$Char_three" == "3" ]]; then 
 Char_three="-wx"
elif [[ "$Char_three" == "2" ]]; then   
 Char_three="rwx"
elif [[ "$Char_three" == "1" ]]; then   
 Char_three="-w-"
elif [[ "$Char_three" == "0" ]]; then   
 Char_three="---"
fi  

while IFS= read -r line;
  do
  j=1
  perm_1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 2-4)
  perm_2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 5-7)
  perm_3=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c 8-10)   
  Def_Chmod=$(echo "$line" | sed -i "$j s/$perm_1$perm_2$perm_3/$Char_one$Char_two$Char_three/;" "$Input")                
    j=$((j+1))
  done <"$Input"
```

**test.txt**

```
-rwxrwxr-x test_1.txt
```

**Output**

Content of the `test.txt` file after the execution of the above code.

```
-rwxr-x--- test_1.txt
```

Comment: Consider using [GNU `gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) or [GNU `guile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/). Both are more appropriate tools than the shell for your problem

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9518/22470

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
IN=750
Input=test.txt

str="-rwxrwxrwx"                        # start with the full permissions
for (( i=0; i<${#str}; i++ )); do       # loop from LSB to MSB
    j=$(( 1<<i ))                       # j changes as 1, 2, 4, 8 ...
    if (( ( 8#$IN & j ) == 0 )); then   # the bit is "off"
        str=${str:0:9-i}"-"${str:10-i:i}
                                        # then replace the position with "-"
    fi
done
# echo "$str"                           # just for debugging

sed -i "s/^[-rwx]\{10\}/$str/" "$Input" # update the permission string
```

Then `test.txt` will be modified as:

```
-rwxr-x--- test_1.txt
```

- It first defines a variable `str` with full permissions to start with.
- Then examine the variable `IN` from the LSB to the MSB bit by bit.
- If a bit slice of `IN` is `0` then replace the associated flag with a dash `-`.
- Finally modify the file `Input` with the calculated string.

Note that you don't need to create the `while` loop to read the
input file line by line. `Sed` will do the iteration for you.